# How to get public link of telegram document files using telegram API?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm developing small telegram bot using java and want to download the document files sent to the bot on the server but, how to get the public link of the document/audio/video file using API calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually possible to download a file from a Telegram Bot but you are limited to 20MB.

[image]

Here is is an example code in PHP

```
if(isset($message['photo'])) {
  $urls = [];

  foreach($message['photo'] as $photo) {
    $response = apiRequest('getFile', [
      'file_id' => $photo['file_id']
    ]);

    $file_path = $response['file_path'];

    $urls[] = 'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot' . BOT_TOKEN . '/' . $file_path;
  }

  foreach($urls as $url) {
    apiRequest('sendMessage', [
      'chat_id' => $chat_id,
      'text' => $url
    ]);
  }
}
```

This is based on the [example bot code](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples/hellobot) of the FAQ